# devenv /runexit command does't closes visual studio instance?

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, devenv

I'm in the process of automating my applications. I'm using...

```
devenv.exe /runexit "solutionfile\path\filename.sln"
```

I'm running my applications. If any exceptions occurred in the above process, Visual Studio doesn't exit and my automation returns success.

I've searched for other command line switches but couldn't found a solution to this. Could anyone please share some solutions for this?

Comment: is there any solutions for this ?.